# Rename object root with dynamic value

Tags: javascript

I have an object like:

```
{ color: blue, type: color }
```

I'm trying to reformat it to be nested within another object:

```
{
 object: 
 {color: blue, type: color}
}
```

With the trick being that the root name of the object (`object` in the example above) will be the value of a variable, not hard coded.

I can create it with a hardcoded solution like:

```
let obj = { color: blue, type: color }
let newObj = {
 obj
}
```

I've tried using `Object.keys(obj).map(key => {})` in various flavours but haven't been able to come close to the solution, it always ends up renaming the keys in in the 'inner' object

I feel like I'm missing something obvious and fundamental but I'm stumped

Comment: `let newObj = obj`

Comment: `{ [name]: obj }`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yep, that's spot on. Thanks for the swift response. I could only find answers that dealt with renaming multiple object keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use { [NAME] : OBJ }. Here an example:

```js
function getObjectName() {
  const myObject = { color: "red", name: "red color" };
  
  const newObject = { [document.getElementById("name").value] : myObject }
  
  console.log(newObject);  
}
```

```html
<input id="name" onChange="getObjectName()">
```